# Flutter BuildContext extension not working

Tags: flutter

Here is my extension file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

extension BuildContextExtensions on BuildContext {
    void snack(String text){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(this).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(text)));
    }
}
```

When I try to call it `context.snack("asd");` it shows that `The method 'snack' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'`. And if I hover on the context it says `package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart BuildContext get context`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to manually import the file with the extension class into the file where it is used. Android studio didnt suggest me to import it. If i wrote the class name, only then it suggested to import it.

Answer (score 0):

Every extension in dart needs a name, try adding a name to your extension

```
extension CustomSnackBar on BuildContext {
    void snack(String text){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(this).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(text)));
    }
}
```

Comment: @lxknvlk it works for me!, I suppose you are using `context` from `dart:js` and not material package

Comment: thanks for comments, i have found the root problem, the extension file was not imported